# how can i force a software run udp way?

Tags: 14.04, networking, games

i want to know if i can force an specific program to use the udp protocol instead tcp on ubuntu 14.04?? There is any way to achieve this?? I need to jump a vlan and udp connections make the job.

Comment: which program ?

Comment: I m talking about a game, specifically Warcraft III 1.26, i need connecting me to a battlenet using udp instead tcp, because a private vlan.

Comment: ask the developers of warcraft 3 / battlenet  ;)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just force a program to use UDP instead of TCP, without rewriting parts of the program itself. These protocols are just too different to be interchangeable.

- TCP is stream-oriented (the receiver sees everything as a continuous
  stream in the exact order that the sender output it); UDP is
  datagram-oriented (each datagram is sent in a separate packet, and
  they can even get reordered).
- TCP has flow control, so the sender (or the sender's OS) knows
  exactly how fast it should send data without overflowing the link or
  significantly affecting other connections. UDP doesn't do any of this
  – a poorly-"forced" program might start sending gigabytes of data per
  second over UDP, regardless of link speed
- TCP has retransmission, so if a packet is dropped in the middle (e.g.
  because the network is overloaded or has other problems) it will be
  resent. If the protocol depends on a reliable transport and you force
  it to go over UDP, the connection might die completely as soon as at
  least a single packet gets lost. (And packets will get lost; see
  points #1 and #2 above.)

Hope this helps!